# Autosort google sheet by date

Tags: google-sheets

I have a survey through qualtrics that has a workflow to import to google sheets. However, when it adds a row to my sheet, the row is at the bottom. What script can I use to make all rows in my google sheet automatically sort by the date column (column G (7)), spreadsheet is from column A through column CK.

I do not want to use a separate sheet to do this, I want it to sort in Sheet 1.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. "What script I can use" is not a proper wording for questions for this site. If you need the sheet sorted after a new row is appended, use an on-change installable trigger that calls a sorting function writing using JavaScript. Start by learning about Google Apps Script at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and installable triggers at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable.